# I don't have ChatHub on my server side. How to add reference of chat hub in signalR from some other application?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Actually i have two projects i want when some activity is performed in my 1st project a notification is shown in my 2nd application both applications are asp mvc4 applications within a single solution.

Comment: Actually i do not have money and i want a ferrari!!!!! Have you google it? There plenty of examples in internet.

Comment: yeah i saerch it on google but it shows examples where we have have chathub class in same project so easily we can make a refrence of that class in jquery butmy problem is that i do not have chathub class in same project it exist in some other project

Comment: Add reference to chathub project

Answer (score 0):

Look for "cross domain" inside SignalR documentation. Server and Client are 2 separate things in SignalR, you can use them in different projects, you basically have to specify the full path to reach your server hub in the client project, and enable cross domain support, but check [docs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#crossdomain) for details.